# Draw line between tiles of tiled map in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, android, tiled

I want to draw line between two tile of my .tmx map in libgdx . I want to get a tile position but not in pixels , in maps grid numbers like : (0 , 6 ).
or is there any way to change a tile color in libgdx.
i can get tile like below:

```
layer=(TiledMapTileLayer)tiledMap.getLayers().get(0);
layer.getCell(row, col).getTile()
```

but can not to draw some thing on the tile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `ShapeRenderer` to draw a line from one cell to another. If you set the `Camera` used by the `ShapeRenderer` then the coordinates will be tile coordinates (plus an adjustment of (0.5, 0.5) to get the center of the tile.

```
    shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
    shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
    Vector2 v0 = new Vector2(2, 4);
    Vector2 v1 = new Vector2(10, 8);
    shapeRenderer.line(
            v0.add(0.5f,  0.5f), // Add .5 to each coordinate to get the center of the tile 
            v1.add(0.5f,  0.5f));
    shapeRenderer.end();
```

To change the image of a `TileMapTile` an easy way is to replace the tile with another tile in the existing `TileSet`.

```
TiledMapTileLayer layer =  (TiledMapTileLayer)map.getLayers().get(0);
Cell cell = layer.getCell(1, 3);
TiledMapTile newTile = map.getTileSets().getTileSet(tilesetName).getTile(32);
cell.setTile(newTile);
```

This get the (relevant) `MapLayer` as a `TiledMapTileLayer` and get a `Cell` from that, then by getting a `TiledMapTile using the`getTileSets`and`getTile`methods on`TiledMap` a new tile can be set.

Complete **libGDX** example code (code assumes a map called *test_map.tmx* with a tileset called *terrain* in the `assets` folder).

```
    package com.bornander.sandbox;

    import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.ShapeType;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapTile;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapTileLayer;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapTileLayer.Cell;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

    public class SandboxGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
        private AssetManager assetManager;
        private OrthographicCamera camera;
        private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer mapRenderer;
        private TiledMap map;

        private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;

        @Override
        public void create () {
            String mapFile = "test_map.tmx"; 
            assetManager = new AssetManager();
            assetManager.setLoader(TiledMap.class, new TmxMapLoader());

             assetManager.load(mapFile, TiledMap.class);
             assetManager.finishLoading();
             map = (TiledMap)assetManager.get(mapFile);

            float viewportWidth = 32.0f; // Number of horizontal tiles to show
            float aspectRatio = (float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / (float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
            camera = new OrthographicCamera(viewportWidth, viewportWidth / aspectRatio);
            camera.update();
            camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2.0f, camera.viewportHeight / 2.0f, 1.0f);

            float tileSizeInPixels = 32.0f;
            mapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1.0f / tileSizeInPixels);

            shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        }

        @Override
        public void render () {
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            // When space is pressed, rewrite tile at (1,3) to be tile 32 from tileset 'tilesetName' 
            if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.SPACE) ) {
                String tilesetName = "terrain";
                TiledMapTileLayer layer =  (TiledMapTileLayer)map.getLayers().get(0);
                Cell cell = layer.getCell(1, 3);
                 TiledMapTile newTile = map.getTileSets().getTileSet(tilesetName).getTile(32);
                 cell.setTile(newTile);
            }

            // Render map
            camera.update();
            mapRenderer.setView(camera);
            mapRenderer.render();

            // Render line between center of tile (2,4) to center of tile (10, 8)
            shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
            shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
            shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
            Vector2 v0 = new Vector2(2, 4);
            Vector2 v1 = new Vector2(10, 8);
            shapeRenderer.line(
                    v0.add(0.5f,  0.5f), // Add .5 to each coordinate to get the center of the tile 
                    v1.add(0.5f,  0.5f));
            shapeRenderer.end();
        }
    }
```